# how to remove irrelevant features in document classification from Weka?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka, text-classification, feature-selection

in Weka, text classification have a lot of features after applying feature selection how to remove irrelevant features in process tab quickly not one by one since in text classification the number of feature is high and it needs time to remove one by one.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Remove](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Remove.html) filter for removing ranges of attributes in the Preprocess panel.

But instead of just post-processing the data, you could also change the default parameters of the [StringToWordVector](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html) filter to produce more meaningful output:

- change the minimum term frequency (option: `-M`, property: `minTermFreq`)
- use a [stopwords handler](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/stopwords/StopwordsHandler.html) (option: `-stopwords-handler`, property: `stopwordsHandler`) like [WordsFromFile](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/stopwords/WordsFromFile.html).

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, my question is how to remove 1500 features quickly not one by one since I am working on text classification and the number of features about 2000 so it needs too much time to delete one by one.